# Reading from a text file in java is returning some garbage value

Tags: java, command-prompt

I'm performing certain commands through command prompt and storing the values in a text file.

```
 wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get deviceid > drive.txt
```

Now I want to read the string stored in the text file from my java file. When I try to do this:

```
            try {
            File file = new File("drive.txt");
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            int i=0;
            while ((string[i] = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(string[i]);
                    ++i;

            }
            in.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I get the output as follows:

```
 ÿþD[]E[]V[]I[]C[]E[]
```

how to avoid this?

Comment: 1) You never increment `i`, so the lines keep overwriting each other in `string[0]`.  2) We can't see how you previously populated `string[2]`.

Comment: Note for future readers: The question originally had `while ((string[i] = in.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(string[2]);}` in the question.

Comment: The output from Wmic is Unicode.  Can your code support that?

Answer (score 1):

```
  while ((string[i] = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(string[2]);
            }
```

over there you are missing the `i++;`

However I would advise you to use this structure: Use a `ArrayList` instead of an array, since this allows you to have a self-resizing structure, also instead in the while use the method ready(); from the `BufferedRead` in order to check the end from the document, at the end the for it's just to display the elements in String ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        File file = new File("drive.txt");
        BufferedReader entrada;
        entrada = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        entrada.readLine();
        while (entrada.ready()) {

            string.add(entrada.readLine());
        }
        entrada.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (String elements : string) {
        System.out.println(elements);
    }
```

Comment: even when I add i++ I get the same output

Comment: @Learner check my answer again, see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a string array here? The size of the array may be wrong? Simply use a string instead of array. I tried this and works fine for me:

```
    try {
        String string;
        File file = new File("drive.txt");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int i = 0;
        while ((string = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(string);
            ++i;

        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Apparently the problem is with the UTF-8 encoding :-\

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE, change the encoding type. Go to Edit->Set Encoding-> Others->UTF-8.